# placing bokeh figure into VueJS issue

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, bokeh

In order to satisfy the requirement, I search through the net for some thought, and the following are the methods I found. It seems not to work for my scenario.

Environment setup: Using Vuecli to create the project

Target: I am looking forward to implementing the bokeh into vue project.

I see the following material:
(1) https://github.com/hemma/vue-bokeh/issues/1
Question: the "fetchPlot" function is missing in vuex and the issue is not fixed.

(2) https://github.com/cclc/bokeh-vue
Question: have no idea how to run the code and how to integrate with the Python backend code

(3) https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html
Question: it's the official method, with some methods to implement but how to integrate into Vue.

Huge thanks.